# Whats the appropriate way to react to the delete key in an NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa

I want to remove an item from my NSOutlineView when the user presses the delete key. Is the only way to do this to over-ride the keyUp method of NSResponder? I was hoping for higher level solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its possible to do this without subclassing. Set the NSOutlineView's `nextResponder` (using `-setNextResponder:`) to your controller. In the controller class you can override `-keyDown:` (or `-keyUp:` and then handle the event in your controller class.

Comment: Side note: to remove the beep you'll need to subclass NSOutlineView's keyUp and keyDown. [For more info check out this link](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?TrappingTheDeleteKey).

Answer (score 1):

As of 10.10 you don't need to subclass the view to override `keyDown(_:)` or `keyUp(_:)`. This is because `NSViewController` inherits from `NSResponder` and is now automatically added to the responder chain. This means you can override the methods in your view controller subclass instead which is often more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I think that overriding `-keyDown:` or `-keyUp:` in a subclass is the only way to do this.

Comment: ...note that these are not equivalent; deletion should be triggered on key down, not key up.

Comment: This has now changed as of 10.10 because view controllers are now automatically added to the responder chain.